# Re-fill compilation-mode buffer from shell script

Tags: buffers, emacsclient, compilation-mode

This might require more tricks than just Emacs-fu, but since Emacs is at the heart of it I hope to get some ideas on how to approach my need here.

I use Emacs/Make/gcc as my development environment. I have a script that watches my source files so that whenever a change is saved it rebuilds, run all tests and updates coverage (thanks [cov-mode](https://github.com/AdamNiederer/cov)).

I'm normally running this in a separate terminal window so any compilation errors will show up there, when what I really want is for those errors to end up in a compilation-mode-type buffer in Emacs so I can go to `next-error` with one key-stroke.

Here are my attempts so far:

- run script in a `term-window` - failed to get `next-error` to work
- run script in a `shell-window`- same problem
- run script and collect output in a file which is visited in a buffer - couldn't get that window to auto-update (can I?)

I also want to ensure that `next-error` is from the last "round", but since the buffer is not cleared on a ^L/`clear`-command you would have to step through all the errors unknowing when you are actually on a current one.

Update:

I have been exploring writing the output from the script into a file and then forcing my running Emacs to re-read it using `auto-revert-mode` while still keeping the `*compilation*`-like behaviour in that buffer. This works, but the problem is that `next-error` can't be reset to start from the new errors after reverting. Using `` C-u C-x ` `` just errors with "Moved past last error". Not even using the `after-revert-hook` to do `(next-error 4 t)` seems to do the trick.

How can I reset the `next-error` "pointer" in this scenario?

Or are there any other approaches I should try?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: "couldn't get that window to auto-update (can I?)" -- `auto-revert-mode` ?

Comment: You might also consider whether your compile step could actually run `compile` inside Emacs?

Comment: @phils what are you thinking with "actually run `compile` inside Emacs"? Externally making Emacs run the compile through some scripting or PPC? If so how could I do that?

Comment: @Drew sorry about the erroneous tag... Learning.

Comment: `auto-revert-mode` actually retain `compilation-mode`, so that's good. Only issue is that it's impossible to reset the error "pointer" to the beginning of the buffer. Not even `C-u next-error` helped. Is there a hook for "on auto-revert" that could be used?

Comment: Yes, `after-revert-hook` should probably do the trick...

Comment: @thoni56 "Externally making Emacs run the compile through some scripting?" -- Yes, if Emacs is running as a server then `emacsclient` can send it commands, and so you could trigger `compile` from an external script.  It sounds like you might have things working without that, but you might still find it interesting to look into.

Comment: Or for that matter, *without* using a server, you could have Emacs keeping tabs on some marker file, and running `compile` whenever it is updated.  The same `auto-revert-mode` mechanisms could be used to drive that.

Comment: Right, then the `compile` would give me a new buffer in which `next-error` definitely should work. I'll investigate that too. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I would ask are you sure this needs to run automatically?  It would drive me crazy to have compilation always occur after I save a file.  Otherwise, you could adopt a more standard workflow where you set ‘compilation-command and just call ‘compile on demand; then ‘next-error will just work. If your heart is set on it, I would recommend exploring having the notification occur on Emacs. Either using its built-in file notifications, or more simply, calling ‘compile from ‘after-save-hook as long as your hook function determines that this file belongs to your project.

Comment: @InHarmsWay, yes. I'm a strong TDD proponent and moving towards TCR. Having the system compiled and tested on every file save has been one of the biggest performance boosts in my coding. But then I (almost) always do TDD and/or refactoring and use C-u C-x s, to save all modified buffers at once. But thanks for the idea with `after-save-hook`, I'll add that to my options to explore too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar script, and I just run it directly from `M-x compile`.  In my case, the script runs continuously once started and triggers a recompilation on file change.  Sounds like that should work for you?  You'd run `utman make debug unit test` from `compile`, don't invoke emacsclient or anything.

Then, to get `next-error` working correctly on recompile, I do this.

1. Add a function to `compilation-filter-hook` to watch the script output for a special string the script emits on recompilation (for example purposes let's say that string is "Change detected, recompiling ...")
2. Call `compilation-forget-errors` when the string is found.  (Note that the manual doesn't advertise this function, I found it by hunting around in the compile.el source code.)
3. Not technically necessary, but for quality of life I after-advise `compilation-forget-errors` to reset the mode-line counts of errors / warnings / info lines.  For some reason it doesn't do that by default (in Emacs 27.1)

All in, my code snippet looks like this:

```
;;; this runs with the *compilation* buffer current.  see the documentation
;;; for `compilation-filter-hook'
(defun my/forget-compilation-errors ()
  (let ((inserted-string (buffer-substring-no-properties
                          compilation-filter-start (point))))
    (when (string-match-p "Change detected, recompiling" inserted-string)
      (compilation-forget-errors))))

(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook #'my/forget-compilation-errors)

(defadvice compilation-forget-errors (after reset-num-errors-found activate)
  (progn
    (setq-local compilation-num-errors-found 0)
    (setq-local compilation-num-warnings-found 0)
    (setq-local compilation-num-infos-found 0)))
```

---

*Actually* that snippet up there is a bit of a lie.  It's what I had at first.  These days I *actually* always give a prefix argument to `compile` so that I get `comint-mode` + `compilation-shell-minor-mode`.  That way I can interact with my script if it prompts for input, which it does sometimes, and I can cleanly shut it down with C-c C-c.  The same principles apply, it's just I have to use a different hook.  So my *actual* code snippet now looks like:

```
(defun my/forget-compilation-errors (inserted-string)
  (prog1 inserted-string
    (when (string-match-p "Change detected, recompiling" inserted-string)
      (compilation-forget-errors))))

(add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions #'my/forget-compilation-errors)

(defadvice compilation-forget-errors (after reset-num-errors-found activate)
  (progn
    (setq-local compilation-num-errors-found 0)
    (setq-local compilation-num-warnings-found 0)
    (setq-local compilation-num-infos-found 0)))
```

Comment: This worked really well. Thank you. Just to clarify, the only difference between the two implementations is that you can interact with your program/script in the second version?